# Handling JWT token renewal within Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I've recently been working on setting up a project to use Azure and part of that involves requesting a token to access a REST API. I've been told that the token will expire in 30 minutes, but calling the API to get a new token isn't particularly expensive. I can do all this without any issue, but I'm curious if Camel has anything built in that can handle this for me without having to explicitly call to get a new token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anything built in, but you could have a timer route that runs every 25 minutes that requests a token and puts it in some kind of global state.

```java
from("timer:getAuthToken?period=1500000")
    .to("http:myKeyServer/getKey")
    .process(new MyKeyProcessor()) // store in global state, static, spring, etc.
```

Then any route that needs the key can get it from global state and set it in a header or exchange property.

Comment: Pretty much matches what I thought, but I decided to just generate a new token if I get something like a HTTP 401. Saves having to deal with thread safe state. I'm lazy :)

Comment: Yep, whatever works. Camel has some nice caching components too if you wanted to let the cache handle that.